# Classify the continuous bilinear functional on $L^p \times L^q$.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functional-analysis

Let $1<p<\infty$, $1/p+1/q=1$ and let $L(\cdot,\cdot)$ be continuous bilinear functional on $L^p(\mathbb{R}) \times L^q(\mathbb{R})$. The continuity means that if $f_{n} \rightarrow f$ in $L^p$ norm and $g_{n} \rightarrow g$ in $L^q$, then $L(f_{n},g_{n}) \rightarrow L(f,g) \in \mathbb{R}$.

Example 1.
Define
$$L_{0}(f,g)=\int_{R} f(x)g(x)\phi(x)dx=\int_{R^2}f(x)g(y)\phi(x)d\delta_{y}(x)dy$$
for some $\phi \in L^\infty$. Then you may notice that $L_{0}$ is continuous bilinear functional on $L^p \times L^q$.

Example 2.
Define
$$(\int_{R}f(x)\phi_{0}(x)dx)(\int_{R}g(y)\phi_{1}(y)dy)=\int_{R^2}f(x)g(y)(\phi_0(x)\phi_1(y)dx)dy$$
for some $\phi_0 \in L^q$ and $\phi_1 \in L^p$. Then it is also continuous bilinear functional on $L^p \times L^q$.

Now, this is my question.

> If $L$ is continuous linear functional on $L^p \times L^q$, is there exist a measure $\mu(x,y)$ such that
>   $$L(f,g)=\int_{R}f(x)g(y)d\mu(x,y)dy$$
>   for all $f \in L^p$, $g \in L^q$?

First, fix for some $f_0 \in L^p$. Then by duality,
$$L(f_0,g)=L_{f_0}(g) =\int P(f_0)(y)g(y)dy$$
and $P(f_0) \in L^p$. Since we assume that $L$ is bilinear, we get $P(f_1+f_2)=P(f_1)+P(f_2)$ for any $f_1, f_2 \in L^p$. Now fix $g_0$ and repeat this process. Then we get
$$L(f,g) = \int P(f)(x)g(x)dx = \int f(y)P^*(g)(y)dy$$
We can easily see that $P$ is bounded operator on $L^p$. But it is not enough to classify  the form of $L$.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If the boundedness of $P : L^p \to L^p$ is really not sufficient to conclude what you want, you have a problem/disproved your claim, because any linear, bounded $P$ of that form yields a bilinearform via $L(f,g) := \langle Pf, g\rangle$.

Comment: @PhoemueX Oh, I see. We have an 'if and only if' condition. But My intension of 'it is not enough to classify the form of $L$' is not 'I have a counterexmaple' but 'I can't progress anymore'. Is there an example that $P$ is bounded but $<Pf,g>$ cannot be represented as the form of $\int fgd\mu dx$?

Comment: i.e. Is there a $P$ such that $f \in L^p$, $||Pf||_p \leq C ||f||_p$, $P(f+g)=P(f)+P(g)$ but $(Pf)(y)$ is not the form of $\int_{R}f(x)d\mu (x,y)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is more of a comment, but too long:

I think part of the problem is, that you do not empose restrictions on the "measure".

It should be straightforward to convince yourself that a positive measure does not suffice in general, so you need signed measures. In your first example, the measure will be something like

$$\mu(A) = \int \phi(x) \chi_{A}(x,x) dx$$

if I am not mistaken (this should at least hold for precompact $A$ or something).  Note that e.g. for $\phi = \chi{(0,\infty)} - \chi_{(-\infty,0)}$, this is **not** a signed measure, as it will assume both values $\infty$ and $-\infty$. Even the restriction to compact sets does not admit an extension to a signed measure as it would have to be bounded above **or** below.

Comment: Nice comment. The structure theorem may be more complicating and more difficult than I exptected.